# How to evaluate this type of arithmetic syntax tree in general?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a syntax tree, like this:
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSuYr.png)

I can evaluate any syntax tree easily when there are no terms, with a similar code (I wrote a simpler pseudo code):

```
double evaluate(Node node){
   if(numeric(node.value))
      return node.value;
   else{
      Operator op = getOperator(node);
      double v1 = evaluate(node.leftNode);
      double v2 = evaluate(node.rightNode);
      switch(op)
         case ADD:
            return v1 + v2;
         ...
   }
        
}
```

I guess I should receive a simpler tree instead of a double, but I have no idea how to simplify in a good way.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.  It looks like your code (if completed) will evaluate an expression tree.  What do you mean by "simpler tree" and "in general"?

Comment: Your code looks perfectly correct and like one of the usual ways of doing this.